# Position a text in an image

Tags: html, css, css-position

```html
<head>
<style>
.relative{position:relative; width:600px;}
.absolute-text{position:absolute; bottom:1; font-size:12px; font-family:"vedana"; background:rgba(251,251,251,0.5);
padding:10px 20px; width:10%; text-align:center;}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="relative">
 <img src="Chttps://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss3PX.jpg">
  <p class="absolute-text">16<br>august</p>
</div>

                                          

</body>
```

I have a image and want some text in button-left corner of that images using html and css... 
here is an image something looks like that:

[image]

I tried many times but it didn't came..

Comment: Can you share the codepen or jsfiddle link for the code you have tried. In general you can check for this link as reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Comment: above is code, but it didn't fixed at button

Answer (score 3):

You have to use css position absolute and position relative. make parent relative and child relative.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/hamburger.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning to independently place the text and the image. This allows you to place text anywhere on the page, including on top of an image.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

html:

```
 <div class="img">
    <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.img{
    background-image: url('img_location');
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
a{
    display: block;
   position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give `px` after 1 in this line `bottom: 1;`

```css
.relative{
  position:relative; 
  width:600px;
 }
 
.absolute-text{
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-family: "vedana"; 
  background: rgba(251,251,251,0.5);
  padding: 5px 10px; width:10%; 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<head>
<style>



</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="relative">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss3PX.jpg">
 <p class="absolute-text">16<br>August</p>
</div>

                                          

</body>
```

Comment: ya, here i forget to give px, but i forget to  give margin:0 . now i got output.. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

-> so simple when you write bottom:1; change bottom:0;

-> remember when you write greater than 0 value in css please write value with px example 1px, 2px, etc.

```css
<head>
<style>
.relative {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
}
.absolute-text {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  font-size:12px; 
  font-family:"vedana";
  background:rgba(251,251,251,0.5);
  padding:10px 20px;
  width:10%; 
  text-align:center;
}


</style>
</head>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="relative">
    <img src="Chttps://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss3PX.jpg">
    <p class="absolute-text">16<br>august</p>
  </div>                                        
</body>
```